# Setting Default Activity Android

Tags: java, android

Trying to create a default activity (the one that loads when the app starts).

My code in the manifest.xml is as follows:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Start"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

However this is not working. Anyone have any ideas? The activity I previously set as default is loading instead.

here is my complete Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.samstone.ringoffire"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
         <activity
            android:name=".Start"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start" >
           <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.samstone.ringoffire.RingOfFire"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.samstone.ringoffire.AddRules"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_rules" >
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

It loads up RingOfFire activity as default.

Comment: delete your gen folder and force regenerate from ide?

Comment: How would I force regeneration?

Comment: Just done it, it hasn't fixed it :(

Comment: the ide should do it automatically when you build, but some ide's you can force by right clicking on the project and there is an option (you probably won't need to do this) delete, then build & it will regenerate.

Comment: It has not fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

> The activity I previously set as default is loading instead.

Reboot the device or emulator in question. The home screen can elect to cache this sort of information and therefore may not detect your changes in `<intent-filter>` values.

Comment: This didn't work. I have posted my complete XML file. 

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @SamStone: Uninstall the app, ensure that you have done a fresh build of the app, then install the revised app. Also, consider deleting the `DEFAULT` category, as it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

put in the full name for your starting activity just like you did for your other activities and get rid of android.intent.category.DEFAULT

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm using IDEA. In Run => Edit Configurations... you can set which Activity will launch first (you can set there a default Activity that will solve your problem).